# How to set spacing for a single chapter/section/subsection?

Tags: spacing, floats, sectioning

I have the problem that I get a huge space under the section title for some sections when importing a figure. I use the `scrreprt` document class. Is there a possibility to change the spacing under a specific section header? I really mean a specific header, i do not want to change the spacing of other headers.

Comment: figures normally float to avoid adding large spaces. It os hard to guess why you have a large space if you give no clue about your input.

Comment: Hard to say without see any code nor the output, but  most propably the problem is that you are not using float figures or using floats with too restrictive options like `[H]`.

Comment: This is not a problem with the section title but how you are importing a figure, which you do not tell us.